# Difference between these CSS reset methods

Tags: html, css

I would like to know if there is any difference between these two methods.

`body,ul,li,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none;}`

and

```
body,ul,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{padding:0; margin:0;}
li{list-style-type:none;}
```

without the need to use the global selector `*`
The real issue here is that, I have mentioned `list-style-type:none;` in the first example, even though this attribute applies to the `li` tag on. But, I find myself something in need to group all elements and just give them values , even if some values don't apply to some elements.

So, is there a negative side to that aside from clarity issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the second reset.. although I always use Eric Meyers..

The first reset applies `padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none;` to all the tags. This is really redundant, as `list-style-type:none` has absolutely no effect on `h1`, `h2`, etc. Why apply it if it has no effect on those elements? Don't.

`list-style-type:none` only has effect on `<ul>` and `<li>` therefore it should only be applied to those, as in the second example.

**Of those 2 options, use the following:**

```
body,ul,li,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5{padding:0; margin:0;}
ul,li{list-style-type:none;}
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the second set of rules does not set margin and padding on `li` elements.

Regarding the question about setting `list-style-type` on elements other than `li`, it is not an error and does not cause problems as such. It may have an effect, though, since those elements still have the property and their children may inherit it. For example, if another style sheet sets `h2 { display: list-item }`, then it matters what the `list-style-type` value for `h2` is.